# Specify unique newline character (for upload to R)

Tags: r, shell, newline

I have a pipe delimited file with several embedded '\n' characters per row, but a unique pattern that I would like to substitute as a '\n' prior to importing into R.

For example, a sample text document might look like:

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
ID1|num1|num2|text\n text\n text[uniquepattern]\n
ID2|num3|num4|text2\n tex2\n text[uniquepattern]\n
```

I would ideally like the above to be loaded into R as a dataframe with two rows as follows:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | num1 | num2 | text text text |
| ID2 | num3 | num4 | text2 text2 text2 |

Without specifying that [uniquepattern] should be treated as a newline, R will upload this row as several rows. My initial solution was to use shell scripting to process the file beforehand. Something like:

`tr '\n' ' ' < original_file.txt > temp_file.txt`

`tr '[uniquepattern]' '\n' < temp_file.txt > final_file.txt`

However this doesn't seem to work. Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)

file1 <- read_lines("COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4
ID1|num1|num2|text\n text\n text[uniquepattern]\n
ID2|num3|num4|text2\n tex2\n text[uniquepattern]\n")

unsplit_df <- paste(file1[2:length(file1)], collapse = "") %>%
  str_split("\\[uniquepattern\\]") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as_tibble_col(file1[1]) %>%
  filter(str_detect(.[[1]], "[:alnum:]"))

separate(unsplit_df, col = 1, into = unlist(str_split(colnames(unsplit_df), "\\|")), sep = "\\|")

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4           
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          
# 1 ID1   num1  num2  text text text 
# 2 ID2   num3  num4  text2 tex2 text
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I am hoping to actually use '|' as the delimiter and to substitute [uniquepattern] as the newline character. Ideally, R would read in my file as one single row, with the last column as 'text text text' and [uniquepattern] now used to denote a newline. Does this make sense?

Comment: How about these edits? Should X.3 be split into a nested character vector/tibble, or how would you prefer that?

Comment: Closer! I edited my original question to show what I am looking for. Does that make sense? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ok, do my new edits work?